# Referring to a tuple in a list

Tags: python, tuples

Here is my current code

```
scores = [0,2,0,1,0]
enumeratedScores = list(enumerate(scores))
print(enumeratedScores) # outputs [(0,0), (1,2), (2,0), (3,1), (4,0)]
```

From there I am trying to pull out the largest tuple in that list based off of the second value of the tuple. I.e in this case I want it to return tuple `(1,2)`, however in my implementation, it returns tuple `(4,0)`. I am relevantly new to the tuples. What code would I use to achieve this?

Comment: Which tuple do you want if two or more tuples contain the high score? Do you want the one with the lowest index to win, or the highest index? Or don't you care? These options are easily handled with a suitable key function to `max` (or `sorted`).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the named `key` argument of the [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max)  function together with [operator.itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter):

```
>>> import operator
>>> enumeratedScores = [(0,0), (1,2), (2,0), (3,1), (4,0)]
>>> max(enumeratedScores, key = operator.itemgetter(1))
(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `max` function along with the `key` attribute.

```
>>> l = [(0,0), (1,2), (2,0), (3,1), (4,0)]
>>> max(l, key=lambda x: x[1])
(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want, you can sort your `enumeratedScores` and then pluck off the first element:

```
sorted(enumeratedScores, key=lambda tup: (tup[1], tup[0]), reverse=True)[0]
```